# Scale the webpage as a whole to any resolution

Tags: css, asp.net, responsive-design, screen-resolution

I am trying to achieve something in my website. I want it to have a fixed view with no scrollable content horizontaly or vertically. I have achieved this on my PC which is 1280x800. But when I resize the browser or decrease the resolution it doesnot fit anymore and the elements gets scattered up and down. I don't want to use bootstrap and the responsive approach. Is there a way to make the webpage as a fixed block (like PDF) which scale as per the user window. One example I saw and I want to know how to achieve this is the following: [Website](http://www.djsradioshow.com/) As you can see if you opened this site on a mobile device it is the same view but smaller in everything. How can I do this style ?

Comment: In your CSS did you set a width to the wrapper of your website? For example #wrapper{width: 800px;}.

Comment: Use the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers - http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, the viewport meta tag (as suggested by [Luis P. A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3613208/luis-p-a))should do the trick.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

There's a pretty nice article on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/probably-use-initial-scale1/) about it.

Comment: I will try the viewport - but I don't think this is the trick I want. I was trying to scale the whole webpage to match the screen resolutions. not just the mobile devices - I used vw and vh values for most elements in the website and it worked pretty well - except for some few attributes left unhandled correctly - please check [Usher-ma](http://www.usher-ma.com/) and tell me what do you think - I now have a nice view on most screens but mobile devices are not that good